# CSS3 Animation Direction Reverse does not work in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have following animation. It works fine in Chrome but does not work in safari. Although if I remove reverse it starts working in Safari.

Is it possible that animation starts working in Safari in reverse.
OR
It keeps working in reverse in chrome but normal in Safari.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/75KHE/1/)

```
.d{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
  background:url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/chrome_ntp_white_logo2.png) repeat-x;
     animation:mymove  25s infinite linear reverse;
  -webkit-animation:mymove 25s infinite linear reverse; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    0%{background-position:0 0}
    100%{background-position:999px 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i removed reverse since its not supported by Safari and set background-position to -999px instead of 999px;